# How do I assign multiple symbols to the same value in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, data-structures

The idea of what I am trying to do is to clump synonym symbols to the same value, without having to redefine the same value over and over. Basically turn this:

```
fruits = { orange: "Citrus", grapefruit: "Citrus", tangerine: "Citrus" }
```

Into this:

```
fruits = { orange:, grapefruit:, tangerine: => "Citrus" }
```

What is the proper syntax for accomplishing this?

Thanks

Comment: Wouldn't `{citrus: [:orange, :grapefruit, :tangerine]}` make more sense?

Comment: Your question is very unclear. What does it mean to "assign multiple symbols to the same value"? You cannot assign to a value, you can only assign a value to a variable. (And only one value to a variable, not multiple.) What does it mean to "clump" symbols to the same value? I searched the entire Ruby Language Specification, but I could not find a definition of clumping, unfortunately.

Comment: @JörgWMittag we can `collect`, `chunk`, `slice`, and even `clamp` but unfortunately we cannot "clump".

Comment: Ok, let me try and rephrase it; basically I have created ascii blueprints for various motherboards. I have code that automatically pulls the model information from the motherboard and matches it to its corresponding ascii blueprint. The thing is, is that there are hundreds of different models of motherboards that share the same blueprints. So what I am trying to do is find a way to share the ascii blueprints across hundreds of models. I was trying to use a hash for this, and am trying to avoid pasting the same variable over and over to a bunch of different hosts, when they share the same map.

Comment: The commenters are saying that `{ orange:, grapefruit:, tangerine: => "Citrus" }` is not a valid Ruby object, because `orange:`, `grapefruit:` and `tangerine:` are not valid objects and `orange` and `grapfruit` have no values (recall that hashes are key-value pairs separated by commas). `{ orange: "Citrus" }` is shorthand for `{ :orange=>"Citrus" }` but `{ orange: => "Citrus" }` is not valid because `orange:` is not valid.

Comment: @CharlesPersson : Actually, the original code (first line) in your question has the keys in your hash refer to **different** String objects, which just happen to have the same value. Hence, it is not clear what effect you actually want to achieve with the syntactic sugar you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Use a hash, in order to access the type of fruit using the fruit name. For example:

```
fruits = %i{ orange grapefruit tangerine apple }
citrus_fruits = %i{ orange grapefruit tangerine }
fruit_type = citrus_fruits.zip([:citrus] * citrus_fruits.length).to_h
fruit_type[:apple] = :rosaceae
puts fruit_type
# {:orange=>:citrus, :grapefruit=>:citrus, :tangerine=>:citrus, :apple=>:rosaceae}
```

Here, [`zip`](https://apidock.com/ruby/Array/zip) and [`to_h`](https://apidock.com/ruby/Array/to_h) are used to simplify the hash creation and avoid repetitive code.

Comment: `citrus_fruits.zip([:citrus] * citrus_fruits.length).to_h` could be more simply expressed as `citrus_fruits.product([:citrus]).to_h`. That being said the result produced by this code appears to be the input rather than the desired output.

Answer (score 1):

### Group Keys by Value; Optionally Transform Returned Values

In Ruby, a [Symbol](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.0.0/Symbol.html) is a core class that provides an identifier for things, and the Symbol is never duplicated during runtime. Setting aside how they're used internally, the most common use case for *using* a Symbol in your code is to define keys in a Hash. You can use other types of keys, but the properties of a Symbol make them especially useful as Hash keys.

With that out of the way, it looks like you're trying to group similar Hash values, but it's unclear how you expect to *use* this grouping. There is more than one way to do this, so I'll just pick one as an example.

Given a Hash like this one:

```rb
produce =
  {
        :orange => "citrus",
    :grapefruit => "citrus",
     :tangerine => "citrus",
     :raspberry => "berry",
    :strawberry => "berry",
    :canteloupe => "melon",
      :honeydew => "melon"
  }
```

you can use [Hash#group_by](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.0.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-group_by) (inherited from Enumerable) to quickly sort your Hash by value. For example, using Ruby 3.0.0:

```rb
produce.group_by { _2 }
#=> 
{"citrus"=>
  [[:orange, "citrus"], [:grapefruit, "citrus"], [:tangerine, "citrus"]],
 "berry"=>[[:raspberry, "berry"], [:strawberry, "berry"]],
 "melon"=>[[:canteloupe, "melon"], [:honeydew, "melon"]]}
```

This returns a Hash grouped by your unique values, but you may prefer to discard the produce type in the nested Array objects. You can do that with [Hash#transform_values](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.0.0/Hash.html#method-i-transform_values) like so:

```rb
produce.group_by { _2 }.transform_values { _1.map &:first }
#=> 
{"citrus"=>[:orange, :grapefruit, :tangerine],
 "berry"=>[:raspberry, :strawberry],
 "melon"=>[:canteloupe, :honeydew]}
```

Either way, the main point is that a Hash key is associated with a value that can be of almost any class, and so you can examine the contents of each value to determine whether or not they belong to the grouping you want (which is currently defined by your key).

Your current data structure isn't really optimized for retrieving types of produce (e.g. citrus fruits) easily, but it can certainly be done. However, you may want to reconsider whether you have the right data structure for the way you want to access or manipulate your data. Your mileage will certainly vary.

Comment: Equally expressed as `produce.group_by(&:pop).transform_values(&:flatten)`

Answer (score 1):

Your comment about motherboards and blueprints suggest that you are given something like

```
h = { :mb1=>:bp3, :mb_2=>:bp1, :mb3=>:bp3, :mb4=>:bp2, :mb5=>:bp1 }
```

and want to produce the hash

```
{ :bp3=>[:mb1, :mb3], :bp1=>[:mb_2, :mb5], :bp2=>[:mb4] }
```

One of many ways to do that is the following:

```
h.each_with_object({}) { |(k,v),g| (g[v] ||= []) << k }
```

See [Enumerable#each_with_object](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_with_object), and to understand why I've written the block varaiables `|(k,v),g|`, see [array decomposition](https://docs.rubylang.org/en/2.7.0/doc/syntax/assignment_rdoc.html#label-Array+Decomposition).

This is a condensed translation of the following code (which I've salted with three `puts` statement to show the calculations being performed):

```
g = {}
h.each do |key_value_pair|
  k, v =  key_value_pair
  puts "\nkey_value_pair = #{key_value_pair}, k = #{k}, v = #{v}"
  puts "g[#{v}] set to [] because g[#{v}] == nil" if g[v].nil?   
  g[v] = [] if g[v].nil?
  g[v] << k
  puts "g after g[#{v}] << #{g}"   
end
  #=> {:mb1=>:bp3, :mb_2=>:bp1, :mb3=>:bp3, :mb4=>:bp2, :mb5=>:bp1}
```

The following is displayed:

```
key_value_pair = [:mb1, :bp3], k = mb1, v = bp3
g[bp3] set to [] because g[bp3] == nil
g after g[bp3] << {:bp3=>[:mb1]}

key_value_pair = [:mb_2, :bp1], k = mb_2, v = bp1
g[bp1] set to [] because g[bp1] == nil
g after g[bp1] << {:bp3=>[:mb1], :bp1=>[:mb_2]}

key_value_pair = [:mb3, :bp3], k = mb3, v = bp3
g after g[bp3] << {:bp3=>[:mb1, :mb3], :bp1=>[:mb_2]}

key_value_pair = [:mb4, :bp2], k = mb4, v = bp2
g[bp2] set to [] because g[bp2] == nil
g after g[bp2] << {:bp3=>[:mb1, :mb3], :bp1=>[:mb_2], :bp2=>[:mb4]}

key_value_pair = [:mb5, :bp1], k = mb5, v = bp1
g after g[bp1] << {:bp3=>[:mb1, :mb3], :bp1=>[:mb_2, :mb5], :bp2=>[:mb4]}
```

Comment: Thank you! This was spot on and helped me solve my issue!

Answer (score 1):

@Charles Persson, if I understood your question correctly, your main goal is to refactor this snippet:

```rb
hash = {
  :orange     => "citrus",
  :grapefruit => "citrus",
  :tangerine  => "citrus",
  :raspberry  => "berry",
  :cherry     => "drupe",
  :strawberry => "berry",
  :canteloupe => "melon",
  :honeydew   => "melon",
  :apple      => "pome"
}
```

to something similar to:

```rb
hash = {
  [:orange, :grapefruit, :tangerine] => "citrus",
  [:raspberry, :strawberry]          => "berry",
  :cherry                            => "drupe",
  [:canteloupe, :honeydew]           => "melon",
  :apple                             => "pome"
}
```

If I am right, then I can suggest implementing a method like this one:

```rb
# source - an input hash that can contain arrays as keys.
# dest - a new output hash where all array keys are replaced by singular keys.
def mhash(source)
  dest = {}

  source.each_pair do |key, value|
    if key.instance_of?(Array)
      key.each do |sub_key|
        dest[sub_key] = value
      end
    else
      dest[key] = value
    end
  end

  dest
end
```

or its shorter alternative:

```rb
def mhash(source)
  source.each_pair.with_object({}) do |(key, value), dest|
    key.instance_of?(Array) ? key.each { |sub_key| dest[sub_key] = value } : dest[key] = value
  end
end
```

This way, you will be able to write a code like the following:

```rb
hash = mhash({
  [:orange, :grapefruit, :tangerine] => "citrus",
  [:raspberry, :strawberry]          => "berry",
  :cherry                            => "drupe",
  [:canteloupe, :honeydew]           => "melon",
  :apple                             => "pome"
})

p hash
# => {
  :orange     => "citrus",
  :grapefruit => "citrus",
  :tangerine  => "citrus",
  :raspberry  => "berry",
  :strawberry => "berry",
  :cherry     => "drupe",
  :canteloupe => "melon",
  :honeydew   => "melon",
  :apple      => "pome"
}
```

Otherwise, please provide a better explanation of your question. Thanks.